# Magento CMS URL tag language independent?

Tags: magento, content-management-system, tags, hyperlink, multilingual

Is it somehow possible to have language independent CMS tags in Magento?

This works in both storeviews: `{{store url='catalog/category/view/id/10'}}`
output: `www.my-domain.de/catalog/category/view/id/10`

But it would be better if the output would be like this:

`www.my-domain.de/my-category-de`
`www.my-domain.de/my-category-en`

Of course, I can work with custom URL rewriting, but this would be a bit tedious.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correct what you mean, you want language dependent urls, not language independent?

There is the option in *System -> Configuration -> Web -> Url Options* called *Add Store Codes to Urls* which achieves this, assuming you have a different Store View per language.

Hope this helps enough.

Comment: the store code in url will only do that (adding the store's code), but will leave the CMS page's url key the same for each language

Comment: @david parloir, Yes but the url he is referring to is a Catalog url, not a CMS url, so he will need at least this I think.

Comment: you're right, I didn't understood the question right. I think you're answer is the right one then.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but it is not excactly what Im looking for.
I have to storeviews german & englisch.
I have storeview(language) dependent categorynames
Now I would like to have a method to call this categories with one link dependent on the language Im in.
this works:
{{store url='catalog/category/view/id/10'}}
but than I don't have nice seo friendly urls

sry for my bad and maybe confusing english